# How can I scale inline matplotlib figures within JupyterLab?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-lab

I'm trying out JupyterLab having used Jupyter notebooks for some time.  I use the standard %matplotlib inline magic at the start.  I've noticed that JupyterLab displays matplotlib figures much larger than Jupyter notebooks used to.

**Is there a way to force JupyterLab to display the images in smaller window/area?**  I know I can change the figsize I pass when creating the figure but that does not scale the text/labels within the figure and I end up with effectively oversize labels and titles.

Ideally within JupyterLab I'd like to be able to set it up so images fit in an area I can define the size of and if they're larger they get scaled to fit.

I've been reading the JupyterLab docs but nothing leaps out at me at solving this particular problem.

Update: I'm running JupyterLab in Chrome.  Chrome displays images up to the full width of the browser window; if the window is smaller than that width that allows the full size of the image, the image is scaled to fit - this is fully dynamic, if you shrink the width of the window the image will rescale on the fly.  I changed my figsize parameter (and carefully adjusted font sizes to work) and I got a reasonably sized figure in JuptyerLab.  I noticed that when I saved this to a jpg and put that in a powerpoint doc is was quite small (3,2).  So I enlarged it, but it became blurred.  So I regenerated it with dip=1200.  The figure in JuputerLab got bigger. So JupyterLab does not respect the figsize.  It's making somekind of judgement based on the number of pixels in the image.

Update 2: This piece of code demonstrates that the Juptyer Lab front end doesn't display images according to the figsize parameter but the product of figsize and dpi (upto the width of the screen, after which it is scaled to fit, presumably by Chrome itself).  Note that the font size you see on the screen scales only with dpi and not with figsize (as it should).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

xys = np.random.multivariate_normal([0.0, 0.0], [[1.0,-0.5],[-0.5,1.0]], 50)

for figsize in [(3,2),(6,4)]:
    for dpi in [25,50,100]:
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize, dpi=dpi)
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        ax.scatter(xys[:,0], xys[:,1])
        ax.set_title('figsize = {}, dip = {}'.format(figsize, dpi))
```

A work around is to work in Jupyter Lab generating figures at a low dpi setting but saving figures at a high dpi setting for publications.

Comment: The default settings for figures in matplotlib is `"figure.size" : (8,6), "figure.dpi" : 100`.  The IPython inline backend uses `"figure.size" : (6.4,4.8), "figure.dpi" : 72` instead. You could use the same rcParams settings in your JupyterLab.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for the suggestion but if I reduce the figure.size I am still left with the fixed sizes of the titles/labels being too big, relative to the plot.  I may be asking the impossible, but I just want the whole thing to scale.  It clearly does scale to the size of the browser (including the titles/labels) but there doesn't seem to be a way of fixing that "bounding box" by setting an option anywhere.

Comment: No, the browser just shows it in the size that the png image has. The image size is determined by matplotlib's figure size and dpi. In case I misunderstand something here, a visual of the problem may be helpful.

Comment: Currently I generate images using figsize=(6,4).  Which is too big.  If I change figsize to (3,2) the figure will be a better size but the titles, labels and legends will be too big - my settings are correct for when I generate images to print but inconvenient when I'm working.  What I would like to be able to do is to tell Jupyter; "what ever graphic I generate; if its too big for this bounding box scale it to fit, if it fits draw it full size.".  Difficult to post images, corporate restrictions and all.